# Track torrent traffic in shorewall

Tags: firewall, traffic, shorewall, accounting, torrent

I use shorewall to configure my firewall. Is there anyway to track torrent traffic using  shorewall accounting?

Comment: Track it how?  Do you want to see what people are downloading?  Do you just want to see if people are using torrents?  Do you want to monitor a tracker that you are running?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the packets for your torrent traffic to the logs by enacting a LOG rule on it, just before the ACCEPT rule for it. For example, if your torrent traffic is on port 5555 you could write:

```
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE
#                                                       PORT

LOG             out-zone        in-zone         tcp     5555
ACCEPT          out-zone        in-zone         tcp     5555
```

These packets will be logged to your `/var/log/messages` by default. Then you can use an analysis tool to visualize this data. I have not used it myself, but after some cursory research the [IPTables log analyzer](http://www.gege.org/iptables/) seems to be a solution.